# How does MacOS utilize both APFS and the native UNIX (Darwin) file system?

Tags: unix, filesystems, inode, apfs

I am sure everyone here knows that Mac OS made the transition to its own, native filesystem, dubbed "APFS", around the release of iOS 10.

However, it is also commonly known that behind the scenes Darwin (UNIX) is employed for standard libraries, filesystems, and other low-level system services that I have not looked into.

My question is how Apple managed to create seemingly fluid interactions between the longstanding UNIX filesystem and the newer APFS (which, not to mention, has 64-bit inode numbers). Thank you.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su] or [apple.se] or possibly [unix.se]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: @shellter see https://superuser.com/questions/1565167/how-do-apfs-and-the-unix-filesystem-work-in-tandem-on-modern-macos-builds, pls have this question removed if you feel that you have the authority to decide where I should ask these questions

Comment: Like 99.999% of the people here, I have only the authority to "vote-to-close" and to comment as to why I am voting that way. The remaining .001% are the moderators and possibly other employees at S.O. You should only post your question to one forum, that is something that really annoys alot of people. AND I really think superUser.com is the least likely forum for such a question. Did you read the help sections for each forum in regards to "On-Topic Questions"? You can delete your own question, there is no need to involve a moderator. and again, the 2nd two forums seem more appropriate.

Comment: All IMHO, so Good luck!

Comment: It's a very interesting question; it's just not a programming question.

Answer (score -1):

Are you talking about storing resource forks?  There is a section in the wikipedia entry for resource forks on this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_fork#Compatibility_problems